# samba + ms excel locking file

Tags: linux, samba

We have samba server with lots of documents there.

Server is in busy LAN, but only two computers works there using two samba user accounts.

Very often Microsoft Excel can not open or can not save particular files.

Here is my samba conf file:

```
[global]
        server role = standalone server
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        server string = nas
        hosts allow = 127. 192.168. 1. 10.

        log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
        # max 50KB per log file, then rotate
;       max log size = 50

;       security = share
        # is replacd now with:
        security = user
        map to guest = Bad User

;       passdb backend = tdbsam

        load printers = no
        disable spoolss = yes

        # prevent printing errors
        printing = bsd
        printcap name = /dev/null

        map readonly = no
        map system = no
        create mask = 0644

        # stop avahi
        multicast dns register = no

        LANMAN auth = no
        NTLM auth = no
        invalid users = root

;       http://zyxel.nas-central.org/wiki/NFS_and_Samba/CIFS
        kernel oplocks = no

[incoming]
        comment = Incoming
        path = /SHARES/incoming
        guest ok = yes
        public = yes
        writable = yes
        printable = no
        force user = nas

;       http://zyxel.nas-central.org/wiki/NFS_and_Samba/CIFS
        oplocks = no
        blocking locks = no
        strict locking = no
        locking = no

        veto oplock files = /*.xls/*.XLS/*.xlsx/*.XLSX/*.doc/*.DOC/*.docx/*.DOCX/~$*/
        reset on zero vc = yes
```

Here is what smbstatus show when file is locked:

```
Samba version 4.6.5
PID     Username     Group        Machine                                   Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15403   nobody       nobody       192.168.1.6 (ipv4:192.168.1.6:64279)      SMB3_11           -                    -
15420   nobody       nobody       192.168.1.19 (ipv4:192.168.1.19:61179)    SMB3_11           -                    -
15388   nobody       nobody       192.168.1.6 (ipv4:192.168.1.6:63303)      SMB3_11           -                    -
15392   nobody       nobody       192.168.1.22 (ipv4:192.168.1.22:63832)    SMB3_11           -                    -
15406   nobody       nobody       192.168.1.22 (ipv4:192.168.1.22:64421)    SMB3_11           -                    -
15402   nobody       nobody       192.168.1.22 (ipv4:192.168.1.22:64194)    SMB3_11           -                    -
15385   nobody       nobody       192.168.1.19 (ipv4:192.168.1.19:60342)    SMB3_11           -                    -
15404   nobody       nobody       192.168.1.32 (ipv4:192.168.1.32:60939)    SMB3_11           -                    -
15400   nobody       nobody       192.168.1.22 (ipv4:192.168.1.22:63985)    SMB3_11           -                    -
15398   nobody       nobody       192.168.1.6 (ipv4:192.168.1.6:63928)      SMB3_11           -                    -
15397   nobody       nobody       192.168.1.25 (ipv4:192.168.1.25:54630)    SMB3_11           -                    -

Service      pid     Machine       Connected at                     Encryption   Signing
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
incoming     15400   192.168.1.22  Tue Aug  8 09:18:19 2017 EEST    -            -
incoming     15388   192.168.1.6   Tue Aug  8 08:50:59 2017 EEST    -            -
incoming     15392   192.168.1.22  Tue Aug  8 09:00:18 2017 EEST    -            -
incoming     15397   192.168.1.25  Tue Aug  8 09:16:57 2017 EEST    -            -
incoming     15420   192.168.1.19  Tue Aug  8 09:30:29 2017 EEST    -            -
incoming     15385   192.168.1.19  Tue Aug  8 08:45:32 2017 EEST    -            -
incoming     15403   192.168.1.6   Tue Aug  8 09:25:41 2017 EEST    -            -
incoming     15406   192.168.1.22  Tue Aug  8 09:29:05 2017 EEST    -            -
incoming     15404   192.168.1.32  Tue Aug  8 09:27:55 2017 EEST    -            -
incoming     15402   192.168.1.22  Tue Aug  8 09:23:24 2017 EEST    -            -
incoming     15398   192.168.1.6   Tue Aug  8 09:17:41 2017 EEST    -            -

Locked files:
Pid          Uid        DenyMode   Access      R/W        Oplock           SharePath   Name   Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15385        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   Hotel all files/Winter 2017 - 2018/Borovets/Euphoria   Tue Aug  8 09:06:18 2017
15385        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   Hotel all files/Winter 2017 - 2018/Borovets/Euphoria   Tue Aug  8 09:06:18 2017
15397        1000       DENY_NONE  0x80        RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   .   Tue Aug  8 09:16:57 2017
15388        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   .   Tue Aug  8 08:51:52 2017
15388        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   .   Tue Aug  8 08:51:52 2017
15388        1000       DENY_NONE  0x80        RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   .   Tue Aug  8 08:51:53 2017
15392        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   .   Tue Aug  8 09:00:23 2017
15385        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   .   Tue Aug  8 09:06:18 2017
15385        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   .   Tue Aug  8 09:20:10 2017
15385        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   .   Tue Aug  8 09:20:17 2017
15402        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   .   Tue Aug  8 09:23:27 2017
15403        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   .   Tue Aug  8 09:26:15 2017
15404        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   .   Tue Aug  8 09:28:20 2017
15420        1000       DENY_NONE  0x80        RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   .   Tue Aug  8 09:30:29 2017
15406        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100080    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   .   Tue Aug  8 09:32:33 2017
15388        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   ПРОФОРМИ/OLD   Tue Aug  8 08:51:53 2017
15388        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   ПРОФОРМИ/OLD   Tue Aug  8 08:51:53 2017
15385        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   WINTER 2017-2018   Tue Aug  8 09:06:18 2017
15385        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   WINTER 2017-2018   Tue Aug  8 09:06:18 2017
>>> 15392        1000       DENY_WRITE 0x12019f    RDWR       NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   Special offers/SPECIAL OFFERS_2017.xls   Tue Aug  8 09:00:56 2017
15388        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   ПРОФОРМИ   Tue Aug  8 08:51:53 2017
15388        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   ПРОФОРМИ   Tue Aug  8 08:51:53 2017
15385        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   ПРОФОРМИ   Tue Aug  8 09:06:18 2017
15385        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   ПРОФОРМИ   Tue Aug  8 09:06:18 2017
15403        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   Hotel all files/Summer 2017/Bansko   Tue Aug  8 09:27:07 2017
15403        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   Hotel all files/Summer 2017/Bansko   Tue Aug  8 09:27:07 2017
15403        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   Hotel all files/Summer 2017/Bansko/Murite club   Tue Aug  8 09:27:08 2017
15403        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   Hotel all files/Summer 2017/Bansko/Murite club   Tue Aug  8 09:27:08 2017
15392        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   Special offers   Tue Aug  8 09:00:18 2017
15392        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   Special offers   Tue Aug  8 09:00:18 2017
15385        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   Special offers   Tue Aug  8 09:06:18 2017
15385        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   Special offers   Tue Aug  8 09:06:18 2017
15398        1000       DENY_NONE  0x100081    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   Special offers   Tue Aug  8 09:17:41 2017
15403        1000       DENY_WRITE 0x120089    RDONLY     NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   Hotel all files/Summer 2017/Bansko/Murite club/All Inclusive Summer 2017.pdf   Tue Aug  8 09:27:12 2017
```

The file in question is:

```
Locked files:
Pid          Uid        DenyMode   Access      R/W        Oplock           SharePath   Name   Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
15392        1000       DENY_WRITE 0x12019f    RDWR       NONE             /DATA/SMB/incoming   Special offers/SPECIAL OFFERS_2017.xls   Tue Aug  8 09:00:56 2017
```

current time on the server is ~9:30

file /DATA/SMB/incoming/Special offers/SPECIAL OFFERS_2017.xls was not open from anyone except from the same user that reported the problem.

Only one Microsoft Excel was started there - I'm trying to explain that is not some problem the user made.

Comment: Excel is quite picky about file locking - if it thinks the file is already open it will offer you a read-only copy. In later versions of excel the is a 'share' option so that it can be edited by multiple users, but I'm not sure how this works with filesystem level file locking. In this case it looks like the file has been opened read only though - close and reopen it and try with other users/or files to work out why?

Comment: file was not reopen, but probably network did drop for a second.

Comment: Does it behave the same if excel doc is shared from Windows file share? Is this a samba or Windows issue? Also, I don't normally set all the locking options you've got, and have not had these issues